# Images stacking on top instead of sliding using Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

My site http://mytempsite.temporary-domain.com

The above page has two images displaying using Owl Carousel but i cant figure out whats going wrong here as i am using examples from the web, so i could have introduced something wrong here.

My carousel setting is

```
<script>

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#banner').owlCarousel({
                    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
                    animateIn: 'fadeIn',
                    items: 1,
                    smartSpeed: 1000,
                    autoplay: true,
                    autoplayTimeout: 6000,
                    dots: true,
                    nav: false,
                    //loop: true,
                    mouseDrag: false,
                    touchDrag: false
                });

            });
        </script>
```

Two images display when they should be sliding across. I am using the latest version of Owl Carousel so not sure if Owl Carousel is the problem or something else? I checked my HTML which looks to be fine and no errors in the Console window (using Chrome)

I have stripped off almost everything from the site to its basic bare bones along with the current Javascript, JQuery, CSS left intact. Any ideas whats going wrong here?

Comment: after the first "slide" everything is gone. because `.owl-stage` gets `transform: translate3d(-1920px, 0px, 0px); `, but anyway. the fix would be `display:flex` instead of `display:block` on `<div class="owl-stage">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not seeing the two CSS files in your source code that the Owl Carousel documentation says are needed for a successful installation ([source](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html)). You will need to include the following in your `<head>`.

```
<!-- change paths to reflect your setup -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
```